DropDown Menu for multi-Signals choose
I am using Streamlit to write a signal analysis web. During usage, we often need to select multiple signals, with similar names, such as door1, and door2. When I type "door" in the Multiselect box, I can only select "door1" once, and then the Multiselect refreshes and clears the keyword I entered. This can be inconvenient when multiple signals are needed. I’d like to ask how I can modify it so that I can select multiple similar signals at once. For example, I only need to type "door" and then be able to select door1, door2, and door3 all at once.
Here’s the current code:
def get_groups(signals: set[str], config_groups: list[list[str]], index: int = 0) -> list[list[str]]: # Get signals set, config groups, and index
    if not signals:
        return []
    st.write("##### Group " + str(index + 1)) # Write group number
    selected = []
    if len(config_groups) > index:
        config_group = config_groups[index]
        selected = [sig for sig in config_group if sig in signals]
    group = st.multiselect("Signals", signals, selected, key="allsignals" + str(index))
    if group:
        groups = [group]
        groups.extend(get_groups(signals - set(group), config_groups, index + 1))
    else:
        groups = [[sig] for sig in signals]
    return groups



As the pictures showed, I typed the "door" and selected the first item, but when I selected it, the search box would be refreshed and clear my keywords. I wanted to keep the keywords and select all of the items that I needed. How can I solve it?
I have tried to ask AI, but I don't want to add a new search box, I just expect when I select one item the keyword that I type is still there, so that I can continue to select the items.

After typing the first part "door" in your case, use SHIFT+CLICK to select multiple entries that match your filter.

For Steamlit multiselect can not be so easy with shift+click, when I click, the item would be choosed and showed in the selectbox, I can not choose other items.
